# How to pass a 2d array of numbers to my .Net controller?

Tags: javascript, c#, arrays

I have a 2d javascript array like this

```
[[2,3],[13,4],[1,19]]
```

and I want to pass it to my .Net controller

My controller header looks like this

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateOrder(int[,] order)
```

My put call looks like this

```
updateOrder(order: number[][]): Observable<any> {
   return this.http.put(this.baseUrl + 'members/edit/set-order/' + order, {});
}
```

but I'm getting an error when I hit the controller saying:

> 'Cannot deserialize the current JSON object (e.g. {"name":"value"}) into type 'System.Int32[,]' because the type requires a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) to deserialize correctly.\nTo fix this error either change the JSON to a JSON array (e.g. [1,2,3]) or change the deserialized type so that it is a normal .NET type (e.g. not a primitive type like integer, not a collection type like an array or List) that can be deserialized from a JSON object. JsonObjectAttribute can also be added to the type to force it to deserialize from a JSON object.\nPath '', line 1, position 2.'

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You don't need to go through (manual) de/serialization and you don't *need* a `List<List<int>>`. I'm able to pass a 2d array of `int`s with a payload like `[[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]]` and the below API interface.

`public async Task<IActionResult> Test(int [,] ints)`

Isn't it your url in the request? You treat the `order` like a string to cat to the url and the body is empty. And when the body is empty, you see that error you're getting. I think what you need is:

`return this.http.put('yourUrl', order, {});`

See [put](https://angular.io/api/common/http/HttpClient#put). (assuming Angular)

Comment: No, you can't do this. I'm trying this and I get the error message above in my OP. Unless you're constructing the array differently than me, but I don't see how?

Comment: @user1186050, how would you like me to prove it to you? It certainly will work if you do it right. Is there something missing from your code?

Comment: yes please! "Is there something missing from your code?" probably, but not sure what as I don't have any problems passing in others data types and DTO's, etc. There might be something that is configured a certain way in the startup or something, but not sure as I've never seen this message before

Comment: I just tried a 1d array and I used a post too, but still can't get the controller method to enter. I can pass a string, that works! WTF!!!

Comment: Quick question - can you show me a hard coded example of the 2d int array in typescript? Maybe I'm not building it right. I'm doing this -> order = [[1,2],[3,4],[5,6]];

Comment: @user1186050, I think I know why mine works and yours doesn't. I slapped up a new endpoint on a project I was working on when I answered this. I was in the process of putting a simple example together for you when I realized that other project was using `IMvcBuilder.AddNewtonsoftJson()` (so not `System.Text`). You can verify for yourself that Newtonsoft will de/serialize an `int[,]`. Not sure that's an option but I can't find it available in the new minimal host in .net 6 so I'll probably delete this soon.

Comment: @user1186050, I did verify I can do a `List<List<int>>` however; is that also still giving you problems?

Comment: I'm not sure what was going on, but I changed up the type being sent over to the controller. I changed from a [[1,2],[3,4]] to a object and read it in my controller as a Dict<int,int> and now it works. I don't feel like going back and trying to figure it out. I'll check your response as answered.

Answer (score 2):

I think you might need to use `List<List<int>>` type instead of `int[,]` in c# from default c# JSON serializer

```
public async Task<ActionResult> UpdateOrder(List<List<int>> order)
```

Comment: That didn't seem to work, but I did find a solution. I stringified it and then in the controller I deserialized it like this var ordering = JsonSerializer.Deserialize<List<List<int>>>(order);

Comment: @user1186050, ouch!